# Contains method of String failing for "." in Java

Tags: java, string

I have a string array as shown below -

```
String[] emails = {"test.email+alex@leetcode.com","test.e.mail+bob.cathy@leetcode.com","testemail+david@lee.tcode.com"};
```

I want to see if the string contains ".","+" and "@". Based on this, I will do some processing on the string.
The issue is contains for "." is failing even if the string has "."
Also, contains is failing for "+" and "@" if the string has "." before "+" and "@".

I dont understand why so? Need help.

Below is the code -

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        String[] emails = {"test.email+alex@leetcode.com","test.e.mail+bob.cathy@leetcode.com","testemail+david@lee.tcode.com"};
        
        if(emails == null || emails.length == 0)
            System.out.println(0);
        
        HashSet<String> emailsSet = new HashSet<>();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < emails.length; i++){
            
            int splitIndex = emails[i].indexOf("@");
            
            if(splitIndex > 0){
                String localName = (emails[i].substring(0,splitIndex)).trim();
                String domainName = (emails[i].substring(splitIndex,emails[i].length())).trim();
                System.out.println(localName);
                System.out.println(domainName);
                
                if(domainName.length() <= 1)
                    System.out.println(0);
                
                if(localName.contains("."))
                    localName = (localName.replaceAll(".","")).trim();
                System.out.println(localName);
                
                int index = localName.indexOf("+");
                
                if(index >= 0){
                    localName = (localName.substring(0,index)).trim(); 
                }
                System.out.println(localName);
                
                if(localName.length()>0){
                    emailsSet.add(localName+domainName);
                }
               System.out.println(emailsSet); 
                
            }
      
            }
        System.out.println(emailsSet.size());
        }
```

Below is the output -

```
test.email+alex
@leetcode.com


[]
test.e.mail+bob.cathy
@leetcode.com


[]
testemail+david
@lee.tcode.com
testemail+david
testemail
[testemail@lee.tcode.com]
1
```

Comment: Why bother with contains "." ? Just go straight to `localName = (localName.replaceAll("\.","")).trim();`

Comment: John3136
 Thank you for the suggestion. I know that I can use replaceAll instead of contains, but I want to know why contains is failing? Ideally, as much as I know, contains(".") should give true, but it is giving false as a result of which, statements inside if not executing. Do you have any idea why so?

Comment: Answer has already been given - regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few special characters in [Regex](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/regex.html). If you have to use them in some regex as normal character you need to escape them (using `\\` before them).

`replaceAll` method in [String class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) has first parameter as Regex and here you are trying to replace `"."`, which itself is 1 out of those special characters. So you would need to escape it as below :

```
localName.replaceAll("\\.","")
```

Answer (score 5):

`replaceAll` expects the regular expression to which this string is to be matched as the first argument. You need to escape dot, plus (and other regexp metacharacter) with a backslash.

Even with two backslashes, because Java string requires to escape a backslash with a backslash. It must look like this:

```
localName.replaceAll("\\.","")
```

According to regular expression a non-escaped dot means "any character".

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression#POSIX_basic_and_extended

Comment: ...and in a string literal you have to escape the backslash used to escape the dot....

Comment: You are right :-) I've updated the answer